# How to make object for mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is there way to build complete object for **mongoose** to use as query? When making route for search I need to pass many query parameters and sanitize them in **express** middleware. From those I would like to build query object.

I ended up with something like this:

**Inside midleware:**

```
res.locals.filter = {
   query: ...,
   projection: ...,
   sort: ...,
   limit: ....,
}
```

**inside router:**

```
User.find(res.locals.filter.query)
    .sort(res.locals.filter.sort)
    .limit(res.locals.filter.limit)
    .exec()
```

Is there any way to format my filter so I can pass it all at once? Found some examples but nothing seem to work for me...

**In other word do something like:**

```
User.query(filter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out by **JohnnyHK**, the style of `find` call with object fields like `$query` and `$orderBy` was only supported in the shell (and is now **deprecated**) so there isn't any built-in support.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `query` as a [static](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) method on your schema:

```
userSchema.statics.query = function(filter) {
    return this.find(filter.query).sort(filter.sort).limit(filter.limit);
};
```

Which you could then call as:

```
User.query(res.locals.filter).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Thank for input. I was thinking something more like this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441482/order-and-limit-results-in-a-query-with-a-callback). 'myModel.find(filter, {sort: {created_at: -1}, limit: 10}, function(err, items){})' But as one object and use parametr expanding to function, but I dont know their names. Is that make sense?

Comment: @johnymachine That style of `find` call with object fields like `$query` and [`$orderBy`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) was only supported in the shell (and is now deprecated) so there isn't any built-in support and you need to do it yourself.